# DB type change for code first dotnet application

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ef-code-first

I have a dotnet MVC application with codefirst model to SqlServer DB. Can we change the DB to Oracle with same DB schema. If yes, what is the correct way to change DB.

Answer (score 0):

i would say read the link below it will surely help you out to set up  Oracle Data Provider for .NET

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html

after setting up all you need is to run the migrations and voila you are good to go

Comment: If we implement entity framework for sqlserver without using ado.net and giving sql provider name only in db connection string. then creating oracle DB with exactly same schema and pointing the connection string to oracle db and oracle provider should serve the purpose.  Will this work.